# SPFX DynamicForm - Can I add more custom buttons other than save & cancel?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have few questions for DynamicForm package from pnp:

Basically if I need some custom approval buttons in the form (other that default save & cancel buttons), is there a possibility to add it?

Can I hide save and cancel button?

And is it possible to call default save function from my custom button onclick function? Or I have to implement updating the items through API, in that case how would I get field values?

(i use React 17 with class components)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add a custom approval button in the form. Dynamic form packages allow you to define custom actions using properties of the form configuration. You can specify custom buttons and their respective click event handlers to perform desired actions
2. The default save and cancel buttons can be hidden by manipulating the form configuration. Set the and attribute to in the configuration to hide these buttons
3. If you want to call the default save function from the function of the custom button, you can use ref to access the save function of the form

Example:

```
import { DynamicForm } from "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/DynamicData";

class MyForm extends React.Component {
  formRef = React.createRef();

  handleCustomButtonClick = () => {
    // Access the form's save method and call it
    this.formRef.current.save();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <DynamicForm
        ref={this.formRef}
        // Other form configuration properties
      >
        {/* Your custom approval buttons */}
        <button onClick={this.handleCustomButtonClick}>Custom Save</button>
      </DynamicForm>
    );
  }
}
```